# Is it possible to include SqlFunctions.StringConvert in a Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, lambda, expression

I have been learning Expressions and using the code below to add build up an expression against a database model (EF4 - ORACLE not SQL!)

This works perfectly against Oracle, and allows me to dynamically build up predicates such as `"CustomerId", "Contains", 2` into `f=>f.CustomerId.ToString().ToLower().Contains("2")`

However, if I try against SQL Server then it fails because I need to call `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` - but I don't know how to get that included in the Lambda?

My end result would be something like:

```
f=> SqlFunctions.StringConvert(f.CustomerId).ToLower().Contains("2")
```

Thx :)

---

**EDIT: Added example of what I have tried**

This code looks like it almost works, sort of!
However, it throws an error on the `var sqlExpression` line

```
Expression of type 'System.Double' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]' of method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])'
```

```
MethodInfo convertDouble = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToDouble",new Type[]{typeof(int)});
                    var cExp = Expression.Call(convertDouble, left.Body);

                    var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "f");
                    MethodInfo sqlFunc = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new Type[] { typeof(double) });
                    var sqlExpression = Expression.Call(sqlFunc, cExp);


                    MethodInfo contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                    right = Expression.Constant(value.ToString(), typeof(string));

                    var result = left.AddToString().AddToLower().AddContains(value.ToString());
                    return result;
```

---

```
public static Expression<Func<T, string>> AddToString<T, U>(this Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
        {

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(
                Expression.Call(expression.Body,
                "ToString",
                null,
                null),
                expression.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, string>> AddToLower<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
        {

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(
                Expression.Call(expression.Body,
                "ToLower",
                null,
                null),
                expression.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddContains<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> expression, string searchValue)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    expression.Body,
                    "Contains",
                    null,
                    Expression.Constant(searchValue)),
                expression.Parameters);
        }
```

Comment: As per the exception message - SqlFunctions.StringConvert() takes the parameter of double? (i.e. `Nullable<double>`) rather than double type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx). Your cExp expression evaluates to a value of double type. You need to either create an instance of nullable type (i.e. an equivalent of `new Nullable<double>(expression)`) or just cast to double? using Expression.Convert. You may even try using Expression.Convert instead of invoking ".ToDouble()"

Comment: This gets me back almost to where I started from i.e. the SQL provider for EF4 does not support the method...therefore, I cannot call it :(         The specified method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

Comment: Most annoying is that this works for Oracle DB's but not for SQL Server ones.  Oracle have thought to include a "Contains" translation - MS have not :(

Comment: Actually I think functions in SqlFunctions are only for pattern matching. You should just put them in the tree so that EF translates it correctly to the corresponding store function.

Comment: Thats the problem I am having: EF can't translate an Int32 (identity column) into a string to perform a Contains("xxx") on it. e.g. I can use `f=>f.Id==2` and `f=>f.Name.Contains("Fred")` but not `f=>f.Id.ToString.Contains("2")`.  Contains DOES work if I give it a list of exact ID's as `IEnumerable<int>({2, 202})` in which case it returns the ID=2 + ID=202 - but thats not what I really want.  Name.Contains("Fred") translates roughly to `Where Name like '%Fred%'`

Comment: `f.CustomerId.ToString()` works now on the current version (6) of EF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you basically need to build an equivalent expression of the following lambda expression:

```
e => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?) e.Number).Contains("6"))
```

Here is a full copy-paste example. It uses CodeFirst so should work without having to create database or anything like that. Just add the Entity Framework nuget package (I used EF6 but it should work for EF5 as well). Build lambda is what you are really after.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public class MyEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                if (!ctx.Entities.Any())
                {
                    ctx.Entities.Add(new MyEntity() {Number = 123});
                    ctx.Entities.Add(new MyEntity() {Number = 1893});
                    ctx.Entities.Add(new MyEntity() {Number = 46});
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                foreach(var entity in ctx.Entities.Where(e => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?) e.Number).Contains("6")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", entity.Id, entity.Number);
                }

                foreach (var entity in ctx.Entities.Where(BuildLambda<MyEntity>("Number", "6")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", entity.Id, entity.Number);
                }

            }
        }

        private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildLambda<T>(string propertyName, string value)
        {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

            var stringConvertMethodInfo = 
                typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new Type[] {typeof (double?)});

            var stringContainsMethodInfo =
                typeof (String).GetMethod("Contains");

            return 
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Call(
                        stringConvertMethodInfo,
                        Expression.Convert(
                            Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Number"),
                            typeof (double?))),
                    stringContainsMethodInfo,
                    Expression.Constant(value)),
                parameterExpression);
        }
    }
}
```