# LINQ Entity contain searchstring

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have read [Case insensitive Contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring?rq=1), [Why would Entity Framework not be able to use ToString() in a LINQ statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920775/why-would-entity-framework-not-be-able-to-use-tostring-in-a-linq-statement) and many other questions but I still can't figure out the right way.

```
string searchString = "max";
private db = new DbContext();

IQueryable<Person> persons = from m in db.Persons
                          select m;
if (null != persons)
{
     //do what it should but marked as codesmell because of .ToStrong() with no culture
     persons = persons.Where(s =>
        s.person_name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())); 

     //NotSupportedException
     persons = persons.Where(s =>
        cultureInfo.CompareInfo.IndexOf(s.person_name, searchString, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0); 

     //NotSupportedException
     persons = persons.Where(s =>
        s.person_name.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(searchString.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));  
}
```

**What is the right way to do a case insensitive string search in a db with LINQ?**

Comment: this thing is related to database level that what collation is defined on the database

Comment: The LINQ expression has to be converted to SQL.  Not every LINQ expression has an equivalent in SQL.

Comment: Take a look at [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577981/is-it-possible-to-include-sqlfunctions-stringconvert-in-a-lambda-expression). I have done similar things.

Comment: *marked as codesmell* is indeed the only LINQ to Entities supported (hence the right) way. So just use it and move on.